# Lifehacker page no longer loads properly. How do I fix this?

Tags: lifehacker

If Lifehacker site loads at all, it loads looking like a 90s page with a bunch of links left justified and no content. It also takes quite a while to load this very pared down page. I'm going to stop trying to get into lifehacker.com in frustration pretty soon.

Any ideas about whats wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: this has been happening to me as well.

Comment: Have you tried another browser? Do you have any sort of script blocker browser add-ons?

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing a page with all of the content and no styling, it's likely that the stylesheet for that page is not loading.

This is true across the web. If you are seeing it on Lifehacker consistently, it could be a few things:

- They have somehow broken their own stylesheet. This is possible briefly, but unlikely to persist on a site as well-supported as Lifehacker.
- Their site is slow, and the css is loading with a noticeable delay. The only remedy for this is patience.

But what is most likely is that you have a bad version of the stylesheet stuck in your cache. To fix this, you can first try a hard refresh or two (shift+ctrl+R in most browsers). If this does not fix it, try clearing your cache. [This wikihow page explains how to clear your cache in all major browsers.](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache)